# QByteArray to multipart/mixed with base64 encoded

Tags: qt, encoding, multipart

I am a binary data in a QByteArray.  I need to send them over as content-type: multipart/mixed and base64 encoded.  Any way to convert QByteArray to a multipart/mixed content and then encode as Base64?

Any C++ or QT interface will do.

Comment: Hi, just read the doc :o You have `QByteArray QByteArray::toBase64 () const` function. What do you mean by multipar/mixed content ? Do you have a big QByteArray you want to separate into parts or you want to concatenate parts to a big QByteArray ?

Comment: I have already explored the apis in QByteArray.  I a big QByteArray and want to separate into parts.